# Filter date as character

Tags: r, date, dplyr, filter, character

Im trying to filter a new frame by the date. But my dtf shows the "date" variable as character. This is what I have when run str function:

`str(banco_4$dt_inic_tr)`

Console shows: `**chr [1:505057] "07 May 15" "26 May 15" "05 Sep 16" "21 Aug 15" "29 Apr 16"** ...`

What I want to do is : filter the variable dt_inic_tr between "01 Jan 15" to "31 Dec 20".

```
banco_5 <-banco_4%>% 
filter((as.character(dt_inic_tr)>=as.character("01 Jan 15"))&
            (as.character(dt_inic_tr)<=as.character("31 Dec 20")))
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it might be easier to transform the dates, e.g.

```
as.Date("01 Jan 15",format="%d %B %y")
```

This yields

```
"2015-01-01"
```

which makes the filtering a bit easier.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).